# Transform Varchar2 data to number

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have column x that is type `varchar2(26)` and stores values as:

```
0.00, 1, 2, 0.5, 0.25
```

I want to copy these values as number data to other column but I get the error:

> ORA-01722:Invalid number

I have used the following code:

```
ALTER TABLE tmp
ADD (x_1 NUMBER(3,2));

UPDATE tmp 
SET x_1 = to_number(x, '9.99');
```

Answer (score 0):

With the data you have given, that works without erroring. I assume you have more data than you have shown and that one of the values in column 'x' cannot be converted into a number. Try something like this to identify these problem values (I've used -1 as the default, you would need to choose a value that doesn't appear in you table):

```
select
x
, to_number(x DEFAULT -1 ON CONVERSION ERROR, '9.99') x_1
from tmp
where to_number(x DEFAULT -1 ON CONVERSION ERROR, '9.99') = -1;
```

**UPDATE**

Apologies - above example only works for 12c. Easiest way to find the problem data is probably just to eyeball it with a few SELECT statements but if you want to use a coded solution then this will probably work regardless of the Oracle version (adjusting the "return -1" value to ensure it is not a value that actually appears in the data):

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION conv_to_num(x IN varchar) 
   RETURN NUMBER 
   IS conv_num NUMBER(3,2) := 0;
   BEGIN 
      conv_num := to_number(x, '9.99');
      return conv_num;
      exception
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            return -1;
    END;

select
x
,conv_to_num(x) x_1
from tmp
;
```

Comment: . . Does `ON CONVERSION ERROR` work in Oracle 11 and 10?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
MERGE INTO tmp dst
USING (
  WITH bounds ( x, rid, start_pos, end_pos ) AS (
    SELECT x,
           ROWID,
           1,
           INSTR( x, ',', 1 )
    FROM   tmp
  UNION ALL
    SELECT x,
           rid,
           end_pos + 1,
           INSTR( x, ',', end_pos + 1 )
    FROM   bounds
    WHERE  end_pos > 0
  )
  SELECT x,
         rid,
         start_pos,
         TO_NUMBER(
           CASE end_pos
           WHEN 0
           THEN SUBSTR( x, start_pos )
           ELSE SUBSTR( x, start_pos, end_pos - start_pos )
           END
         ) AS value
  FROM   bounds
) src
ON ( src.rid = dst.ROWID AND src.start_pos = 1 )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET x_1 = value
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT ( x, x_1 ) VALUES ( src.x, src.value );
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tmp (
  x VARCHAR2(26)
);

INSERT INTO tmp ( x ) VALUES ( '0.00, 1, 2, 0.5, 0.25' );

ALTER TABLE tmp
ADD (x_1 NUMBER(3,2));
```

Then, after the merge:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tmp;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> X                     | X_1
> :-------------------- | --:
> 0.00, 1, 2, 0.5, 0.25 |   0
> 0.00, 1, 2, 0.5, 0.25 |   1
> 0.00, 1, 2, 0.5, 0.25 |   2
> 0.00, 1, 2, 0.5, 0.25 |  .5
> 0.00, 1, 2, 0.5, 0.25 | .25
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2ec696790fcca2bd08155e17bebe183b)*

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, you have incorrect values.  You could use a regular expression to update only the valid values:

```
UPDATE tmp 
    SET x_1 = to_number(x, '9.99')
    WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('^[0-9]?([.][0-9]{0,2})?$');
```

Answer (score 0):

I precise the question. The column x have values in next rows so the colum looks like

```
   x
1 0.1
2 0.25
3 0.55
4 2
5 3
6 1.25
```

And now i need the same column but wiht datatype NUMBER.